# How can I link certain scene properties (also camera properties) across multiple scenes?

Tags: rendering, camera, scene

I have a character rig linked across multiple scenes I need to be rendered from multiple angles for a variety of animations. However, depending on the animation scene dimensions and frame-length change. In addition, so do camera properties such as the orthographic scale. I use compositing nodes to render out each scene with different cameras to output the frames for the different angles, however it is really frustrating to have to go through each scene and adjust their properties each time I want to render a new animation.

Is there a simple enough way I can link the scene and camera properties (excluding camera and position and angle properties) to a single scene so that I would only need to adjust the values one time?

Comment: Hi :). You can easily link camera data between multiple cameras. But I don't think you can easily exclude some parameters (like view angle, focus point, etc)

Comment: AFAIK the Scene object doesn't abide to the same Object Container > Data Properties as most other Blender objects (Mesh, Curve, Camera, Text, Metaball, Lattice, etc.) so you can't really link one scene and selectively override individual properties. You won't be able to change output dimensions.

However you can link a camera from another file and selectively override its properties with the Library Override functionality.